# Bounded sets with finite minimum distance and sum of measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $A$ and $B$ be bounded sets for which there is an $\alpha>0$ such that $|a-b|\ge\alpha$ for all $a\in A,b\in B$. Prove that $m^*(A\cup B)=m^*(A)+m^*(B)$.

We automatically have $m^*(A\cup B)\leq m^*(A)+m^*(B)$ for any sets $a,b$. Now we must prove the other direction $m^*(A\cup B)\geq m^*(A)+m^*(B)$. So given a countable collection of open intervals that cover $A\cup B$ and has total length $m^*(A\cup B)+\epsilon$, find another collection that cover $A$ and a collection that cover $B$, so that the combined length is $m^*(A\cup B)+\epsilon+\delta$ for some small $\delta$.

I get the idea of the $|a-b|\ge\alpha$ condition that the two sets are somewhat "separated" on the real line. But I don't know how to use it in the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  Cover $A \cup B$ with intervals shorter than $\frac \alpha 2$. Then argue that each interval only intersects one of $A$ or $B$.  Then $m(A \cap$ all the intervals it intersects$=m(A)$

Comment: So any cover of $A\cup B$ can be turned into a cover of $A\cup B$ with intervals shorter than $\alpha/2$ by adding length less than $\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon$, right?

Comment: I wouldn't say "turned into".  I would just say we are promised a cover with intervals shorter than any $\epsilon$ and we apply that to $\epsilon = \frac \alpha 2$.

Comment: Hmm... why are we promised a cover with intervals shorter than any $\epsilon$?

Comment: If you can cover it with any set of finite intervals, you can divide them into subintervals of length at most $\epsilon$.  As they are bounded, you can cover them with just one finite interval.

Comment: Hmm.. but what if the cover is an infinite, countable set of intervals?

Comment: That is why you need the sets to be bounded.  Then there is a finite cover.  Otherwise the measure of one might be infinite.